# Anaconda Navigator 2.4.1 (Python 3.10) Install Packages Got Stuck

Tags: anaconda

Tried to install the following packages from Anaconda Navigator but got stuck!

```
gtk3 (from pkgw-forge)
pygobject (from conda-forge)
graph-tool (from ostrokach-forge)
```

[image: Anaconda_Nav_Install_3_Packages_20230611]

Tried to install the 3 packages from Anaconda Navigator for Spyder 5.4.3 (Python 3.10) but "Solving package specifications" kept looping. Can the 3 packages be installed from Anaconda Navigator? Or must they be installed via other means?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you install using command line instead of Anaconda navigator. From my personal experience the navigator is buggy and provides very few information.

To install those packages, run the following code line by line in your command line tool (Terminal on MacOS, and similar stuff on other operating systems - I'm not sure what you're using though):

```
activate myenv  # Replace "myenv" with environment name
conda install -c conda-forge gtk3
conda install -c conda-forge pygobject
conda install -c conda-forge graph-tool
```

If it still gets stuck, it's probably neither your fault nor Anaconda's. Instead, there might be something wrong with your network settings. In that case, as a last resort, use:

```
pip install package-name
```

Be warned, however, that this might cause unexpected issues. If you do so, create and activate a new environment first so that any potential risks are minimized.

Feel free to ask for any further questions. Happy coding ;-)

Comment: Suggested commands works

Comment: @user22058539 Glad to hear. Perhaps you can mark my answer as accepted so that others will see this question as solved ;-)